# Is this how you use panels?

Tags: 7, panels

I'm learning Drupal and am trying to wrap my head around it. Recently I have been studying Panels. I wanted to see if my understanding of it was correct.

Basically, you use panels for different layouts: 1col, 2cols, 3cols, etc. You can add or apply different content to each of these columns (aka regions?), eg: a node, custom content, a block, widget, form, etc. You can drag and drop where you want these to be within your layout.

You can either set up a 'panel' as a page, by going Structure>>Panels>>Panel Page

Or, you can make turn an existing page (node?) into a panel page by going Structure>>Pages>>Enabling Node view then creating a 'variant' with a Node type specific to the node (page?). We can then select a layout and place elements from the node in panel's regions, like above.

So the reason to use Panels is to simply allow you to place elements, nodes, blocks, widgets, etc in multiple region layouts.

Is this correct?

Comment: That's not all, panels have variants, access rules, selection rules , views integration, passing ulr arguments a bunch of hooks and preprocess functions and a solid ctools background! Panels can get together almost every ingredient of your website with respect to the above. That said, yes, you can use panels either to override a content type's layout or to build a page that will combine some content panes with their contextual filters to feed the panel's variants and display different results per user and role.

Comment: @mchar thanks! But, as far as how content appears on the site, I'm right in saying that it's used for easily organising groups of content, right?

Comment: Absolutely, but that's not all, this is one of the functionalities provided by panels.